# Spring request mapping regex with deeper paths

Tags: regex, spring-boot, request-mapping

How do I use regex to match the following examples in a Spring `@RequestMapping`:

1. localhost:8080
2. localhost:8080/settings
3. localhost:8080/settings/users
4. localhost:8080/settings/users/roles
5. localhost:8080/settings/users/roles/admin

While not allowing these ones:

6. localhost:8080/style.css
7. localhost:8080/manifest.json
8. localhost:8080/api
9. localhost:8080/api/users
10. localhost:8080/api/users/abc

I have this regex `/{path:[^\\.]*}` that seems to only concentrate on not matching URLs with a dot ".". Also, **3.**, **4.**, and **5.** do not work.

I can change the regex to `/{path:[^\\.]*}/*` and then **3.** does work, but **2.** will not work anymore.

What regex must be used to match the above URI (without localhost:8080) of the URLs?

I use it for this FrontendController.java:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class FrontendController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FrontendController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{path:[^\\.]*}/*")
    public String redirect() {
        logger.info("Redirect call to the frontend");
        return "forward:/";
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the pattern that you're looking for? URLs with paths that either start with "settings" or don't have paths at all?

Comment: The pattern should allow any paths in any length (i.e. localhost:8080/one/two/three/four), while not allowing a dot "." or "api" after the first slash "/". Is that a possible pattern for @RequestMapping?

Comment: When responding to requests for clarification (here from @CAustin), it's best to edit your question rather than reply in a comment. In part, that's because not all readers read all comments. That's particularly apropos here, as your comment appears to provide a precise statement of the question, which presently is lacking. Hold the phone: I'm still not clear if the string need begin, "localhost:8080/".

Comment: You should not have that kind of logic in your backend. Don t you have a load balancer like nginx ? It is something that should handle this kind of stuff proxying only the necessary stuff to your SpringBoot app. We can see that your solution won't work If you add internal APIs or new endpoints you wouldn't want to manage...

Comment: Thank you all for the input. It works for this example. Also, thank you for your input @Chasca, separating concerns with i.e. Docker Compose, putting the frontend in one container and the backend in another and proxying them through Nginx surely is a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the following pattern:

`^localhost:8080(?!\/api)(?:\/\w+)*$`

Explanation for `(?!\/api)(?:\/\w+)*`:

-`(?!\/api)` is negative lookahead, ensuring that this point in the pattern isn't immediately followed by `/api`.

-`(?: )` is a non-capturing group, so the pattern it contains can be quantified with `*` as a group.

-`\w+` is one or more word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

https://regex101.com/r/VMf2zE/1

Comment: To permit matching of `"localhost:8080/apiary"` and implement the requirements stated in the OP's reply to your comment on the question, you may wish to attempt to match `^localhost:8080(?!\/api\b|\/[^/]*\.)(?:\/[\w.]+)*$`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cSk1Wr/1)

Comment: @CarySwoveland In the case of `/apiary`, simply adding `\b` within the lookahead should be enough `^localhost:8080(?!\/api\b)(?:\/\w+)*$`

Comment: I agree and that's what I suggested (adding `\b`) , but the OP neither wishes to match strings having a period after the first forward slash, which is why I have the alternation within the lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

This works for the examples you've given:

```
^(/settings.*)?$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/4u88aEIbMDROst).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`^localhost:8080(?!.+\.[^./]+$)(?!/api(?:$|/))(?:.+)?$`

See at https://regex101.com/r/Gbogga/latest

Explaination:

`^localhost:8080` matches literally in the start of string.

`(?!.+\.[^./]+$)` ensures that the path does not lead to a file.

`(?!/api(?:$|/))` ensures that it does not lead to `api` path.

`(?:.+)?` optionally matches path bejont `localhost:8080`